# Android NTLM getting HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, android, authentication, sharepoint, ntlm

I am try to get data from share point server.
Following is my code.

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("masconsult.eu", -1),
            new NTCredentials(username, password, "", ""));
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(webserviceUrl);
    httpGet.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpGet.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
    // HttpResponse response="";
    String responseXML = "";
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
    responseXML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    Toast.makeText(this, responseXML, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have got response HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized. Even I have added all right credential. 
In Chrome browser It working fine with same credential.
plz suggest me any change in code.

Comment: You might not need any changes in your code.  In IE, under Tools > Advanced, ensure that you have enabled "Integrated Windows Authentication", under Tools > Security > Local Intranet zone > Sites > Advanced, ensure the target web site is listed.  Clear cookies and restart IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now its working.
I modified my code with headers.

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new NTCredentials(username, password, "", ""));
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(webserviceUrl);
    httpGet.addHeader("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    httpGet.addHeader("content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    httpGet.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    System.out.println("Responseeee" + response.getStatusLine());
    responseXML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    new JSONObject(responseXML).toString();
```